# ros.org REPs not accessible Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi together,

I tried to read something out of the reps but I can't access them. I tried on 3 different devices.
Not sure who to contact relating this issue, does someone know?
Example page:

- https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0147.html
- https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0000.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350165/ros.org-reps-not-accessible-error-403-forbidden/) by [MrCheesecake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44078/mrcheesecake/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2020-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MrCheesecake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44078/mrcheesecake/) on 2020-04-23**:
info: look like it's woking again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd say, the right way would be to post an issue on the respective repo on GitHub.
As a matter of fact, there is one already :-)
https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/issues/250

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1